# Reinterpolate piecewise polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

I'm curious whether there could be an easy and analytic solution to this problem.

I have a piecewise polynomial defined by polynomials $p_i(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_{k,i}  (x - b_i)^k$ that are valid in uniformly spaced intervals $i$ that have lower boundaries $b_i$. The coefficients $a_{k,i}$ for each interval were determined by curve fitting into data that originated from a smooth physical process. These original data are unavailable.

If the intervals should now be redefined by shifting them equally, $b'_i = b_i - C$, how would one best go about determining new sets of coefficients $a'_{k, i}$ for each shifted interval?

I can only think of a horrifically brute force approach to this, i.e., evaluating the piecewise polynomial over a "fine enough" grid, then redoing a curve fit in each shifted interval to get the coefficients.

Is there a better way?

edit: I've added an illustration.

[Sketch of original piecewise polynomial with per-interval sets of 5th order coefficients (top), and the desired new shifted intervals with new per-interval coefficients (bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hbvV.png)

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you are trying to do? Perhaps a worked example would make this easier to follow.

Comment: I've added an illustration to the post. In the illustration, the long dashed curve would be the original data that were fitted with piecewise polynomials (not splines). Now, having only the poly coefficients of those polynomials, but not the original data any longer, how to derive a new set of polynomials in different intervals that still reproduce exactly the same curve?